# Radmenu hover menu shows up under other Radmenus in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, telerik

I have a radmenu that I generate by examing sharepoint document library folders and building out a submenu structure based on the folder. When I put many of the control on the page, the root menu from other controls shows up over the sub menu of the control. Does anyone know how to prevent it, by altering programatically assigning the style for the `z-index` to the sub menus? See the attached file for a better understanding of the problem. The text was sanitized for public consumption.

Additional Information: When rolling over the menu and the subitems menu shows it does properly cover the other menus and they do not show through. However when rolling over it a 2nd time it definitely shows through, as though its `z-index` is larger.

These controls are each in their own webparts, does that matter? Maybe they're inheriting `z-index`?

The effect only occurs in IE, not in Chrome or Firefox.

My ascx: (customItem is the submenu), these css classes are applied programmatically in code to the root item and the submenu items.

```
<style type="text/css">
.CustomItem
{
     z-index:99999;
}

.rootItem
{
    text-align:center !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;
    z-index:-1;
}
.CustomItem:hover
{
 text-decoration:none !important;  

}
</style>
<div id="section" runat="server" >
<telerik:RadMenu ID="FolderMenu" runat="server">
</telerik:RadMenu>
```

[image: screenshot]

Here is an update: I have reproduced some of bug in the Chrome browser. It seems like an error with the radmenu and not IE. IE just makes the bug happen more quickly.
Here is an example of it not working that can probably be reproduced really easily, at the end is a screen capture video how the z-index messes up.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<telerik:RadStyleSheetManager ID="RadStyleSheetManager1" runat="server" />
<style type="text/css">
   .CustomItem
    {
   position:relative;

    text-align:center !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;
   /* z-index:0 !important;*/

        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }

/* .rootItem
{
    position:relative;

    text-align:center !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;

}*/
   .CustomItem:hover
 {
  position:relative;
  text-decoration:none !important;  

 }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <%--Needed for JavaScript IntelliSense in VS2010--%>
        <%--For VS2008 replace RadScriptManager with ScriptManager--%>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2010.1.309.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js, Version=2010.1.309.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2010.1.309.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js, Version=2010.1.309.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2010.1.309.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js, Version=2010.1.309.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" />
    </Scripts>
</telerik:RadScriptManager>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Put your Java Script code here.
</script>

<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<div>
    <telerik:RadMenu runat="server" ID="FolderMenu" cssclass="CustomItem" >
        <Items>
            <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Item1" >
                <Items>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                     <Items>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     </Items>
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                </Items>
            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
        </Items>
    </telerik:RadMenu>
    <br />
    <telerik:RadMenu runat="server" ID="RadMenu1" cssClass="CustomItem">
        <Items>
            <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Item1" >
                <Items>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                     <Items>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     </Items>
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>

                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                </Items>
            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
        </Items>


    </telerik:RadMenu> <br />
    <telerik:RadMenu runat="server" ID="RadMenu2" cssClass="CustomItem">
        <Items>
            <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Item1" >
                <Items>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                      <Items>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     </Items>
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                </Items>
            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
        </Items>


    </telerik:RadMenu>
    <br />
    <telerik:RadMenu runat="server" ID="RadMenu3" cssClass="CustomItem">
        <Items>
            <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Item1" >
                <Items>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                      <Items>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     </Items>
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                     <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="sub item1">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                </Items>
            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
        </Items>


    </telerik:RadMenu>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the screen capture video showing how it messes up
http://youtu.be/oOdJY65l6AA

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the way you are setting up your RadMenu's it might be best to define a z-index for each one, defining the menus to have lower and lower z-indexes as you go from left to right.

As I believe you can see in your video (at least I saw it when I copied + pasted your code) the second RadMenu (RadMenu1) has a higher z-index than the first one, causing the sub-menu from FolderMenu to appear "under" RadMenu1. I just slightly tweaked the CSS to the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .CustomItem
    {
        position: relative;
        text-align: center !important;
        text-decoration: none !important; 
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index:7000 !important;
    }

    .CustomItemTwo
    {
        z-index:6500 !important;
    }

    .CustomItemThree
    {
        z-index:6000 !important;
    }

    .CustomItemFour
    {
        z-index:5500 !important;
    }

    .CustomItem:hover
    {
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

Excuse the usage of bad names, but you get the idea ;) Then for the RadMenus:

```
<telerik:RadMenu runat="server" ID="FolderMenu" CssClass="CustomItem">
    ...
</telerik:RadMenu>
<br />
<telerik:RadMenu runat="server" ID="RadMenu1" CssClass="CustomItem CustomItemTwo">
    ...
</telerik:RadMenu>
<br />
<telerik:RadMenu runat="server" ID="RadMenu2" CssClass="CustomItem CustomItemThree">
    ...
</telerik:RadMenu>
<br />
<telerik:RadMenu runat="server" ID="RadMenu3" CssClass="CustomItem CustomItemFour">
    ...
</telerik:RadMenu>
```

This prevented the behavior that you saw. So, thinking back on your original issue, if there for some reason is some inheritance of the z-index going on (which can be checked in the chrome dev tools) it might just be easier to explicitly set the z-index of each RadMenu (or the containing element) as this will guarantee the desired behavior regardless of inheritance since properties set on item itself with higher specificity should prevail.

Additionally, it might be helpful to read over this "[Understanding CSS z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index)" article in case the other elements on your page have a z-index set.